# How to playback 3gp files in Java?

Tags: java, audio, playback

I have a java program that receives a 3gp audio file (single file, not stream) sent from the sender in an array of bytes (byte [])

Now, either I need to play this file
or,
I should be able to save it in 3gp format

Example:

byte[] Audiobytes  = received3GPAudioFlie();

Now I want to be able to deal with this Audiobytes in the example.
I have two separate goals,

1. I want to save it as a 3GP file
2. I want to be able to play it as audio file. Thanks.

Please help!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by deal?

Answer (score 1):

If by handle you mean

1) Write bytes to file (save the file) then you can do it as follows:

```
  fileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(strFilePath);
  fos.write(AudioBytes);
```

2) Play the file
[Playing audio files in Java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/playing.html)

Comment: R Thanks for your interest.
I have two separate goals,
1. I want to save it as a 3GP file
2. I want to be able to play it as audio file.

Thanks.